# Integral of $\int \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)} \, dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

How to find integral of

> $$\int \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)}dx$$

I wrote $\sin(3x)=\sin(8x-5x)$ but it generated $\frac{\sin(8x) \cos(5x)}{\sin(5x)}$.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Just wondering, is that an exercise from a textbook?

Comment: One approach is to convert this to an integral of a rational function using the substitution $z=e^{ix}$.  Then, $$\int \frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)}\,dx=-i\int \frac{z(z^6-1)}{z^{10}-1}\,dz=-\frac i2 \left(\int \frac{z}{z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1}\,dz+\int \frac{z}{z^4-z^3+z^2-z+1}\,dz\right)$$It looks ugly, but perhaps tractable.

Comment: @Dr.MV Any method to solve it in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: Yes.  It does have a solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Even though it didn't work out, your idea of writing $8 = 5-3$ was a good one. Did you solve similar problems or did you just get the idea suddenly ?

Comment: @Dr.MV I wouldn't call complex analysis ugly. Can this integral be reinterpreted as Im $\int e^{-2ix}dx$ ?

Comment: @user230452 I got it when I was in thought process of this particular question only.

Comment: @user230452 I never wrote that complex analysis is ugly.  Rather, I was referring to that the latter two integrals in the comment.

Comment: @Dr.MV Can this integral be reinterpreted as Im $\int e^{-2ix}dx$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  $\sin(3x)/\sin(5x)=\frac{\text{Im}(e^{i3x})}{\text{Im}(e^{i5x})}\ne \text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i3x}}{e^{i5x}}\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

Use $\;\sin3x=\sin(5x-2x)=\sin5x\cos2x-\sin2x\cos5x$ :

$$\frac{\sin3x}{\sin5x}=\cos 2x-\sin2x\frac{\cos5x}{\sin5x}$$

Now, observe that

$$\int\frac{\cos kx}{\sin kx}dx=\frac1k\,\log|\sin kx|+C$$

and now perhaps integrating by parts will help.

Comment: After IBP, one is left with the task of evaluating $\int \cos(2x) \log(\sin(5x))\,dx$.

Comment: @Dr.MV True, thank you. It doesn't make things easier (I thought incorrectly that there'd be $\;\cos 5x\;$ inside that last integral). I'm erasing this, and I think this integral is increidibly difficult, although perhaps I missed some trick.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) (that can be used also for sine when you have odd multipliers for the angle) we have: $$
\sin3x = 3\sin x-4\sin^3x \\ 
\sin5x = 16\sin^5x-20\sin^3x+5\sin x
$$
So: $$
\frac{\sin3x}{\sin5x}=\frac{3-4\sin^2x}{16\sin^4x-20\sin^2x+5}=\frac{-\left (4\sin^2x-\frac{5}{2} \right )+\frac{1}{2}}{\left (4\sin^2x-\frac{5}{2} \right )^2-\frac{5}{4}}
$$ Let's convert sines to cosines (they look better when you integrate): $$
\frac{\sin3x}{\sin5x}=\frac{-\left (4(1-\cos^2x)-\frac{5}{2} \right )+\frac{1}{2}}{\left (4(1-\cos^2x)-\frac{5}{2} \right )^2-\frac{5}{4}}=\frac{\left (4\cos^2x-\frac{3}{2} \right )+\frac{1}{2}}{\left (4\cos^2x-\frac{3}{2} \right )^2-\frac{5}{4}}
$$ Now we can decompose the denominator: $$
\frac{u+\frac{1}{2}}{u^2-\frac{5}{4}}=\frac{a}{u-\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}}+\frac{b}{u+\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}} \\ a=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}, b=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}
$$ Then: $$
\frac{\sin3x}{\sin5x}=\frac{\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2\sqrt{5}}}{4\cos^2x-\frac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}}+\frac{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}}{4\cos^2x-\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}}
$$ For both the denominators we have a negative constant term, so let's try to find a solution for: $$
I(a^2, b^2)=\int {\frac{1}{a^2cos^2x-b^2}}dx=\int {\frac{1+\tan^2x}{a^2-b^2-b^2\tan^2x}}dx$$ using $u=\tan x$, $du=(1+\tan^2x)dx$: $$
I(a^2, b^2)=\int {\frac{1}{a^2-b^2-b^2u^2}}du=\frac{1}{b^2}\int {\frac{1}{\frac{a^2-b^2}{b^2}-u^2}}du=\frac{1}{b^2}\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{bu}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}=\frac{1}{b\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{b\tan x}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}
$$ Carefully doing the substitutions I found: $$
\int {\frac{\sin3x}{\sin5x}}dx=   I\left (4, \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right )   + I\left (4, \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right )=   \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3+\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}\tan x+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{4\sqrt{5}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3-\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}\tan x + C
$$

Answer (score 1):

Express

\begin{align}
\sin(3x)& =2\sin x  \left(\cos(2x)- \cos\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) \\
\sin(5x)& =4\sin x  \left(\cos(2x)- \cos\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) \left(\cos(2x)- \cos \frac{4\pi}{5}\right)
\end{align}

Then, decompose the integrand as follows
\begin{align}\frac{\sin (3x)}{\sin(5x)}
=&\frac{\cos(2x)- \cos\frac{2\pi}{3}} {2\left(\cos(2x)- \cos\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) \left(\cos(2x)- \cos \frac{4\pi}{5}\right)}\\
=&\frac{\frac1{\sqrt5}\cos\frac{2\pi}{5} }{\cos(2x)- \cos\frac{4\pi}{5} }
-\frac{ \frac1{\sqrt5} \cos\frac{4\pi}{5}}{\cos(2x)- \cos\frac{2\pi}{5} }
\\
=&\frac{\frac1{2\sqrt5}\cos\frac{2\pi}{5} }{\sin(\frac{2\pi}5+x)\sin(\frac{2\pi}5-x) }-\frac{\frac1{2\sqrt5} \cos\frac{4\pi}{5} }{\sin(\frac{\pi}5+x)\sin(\frac{\pi}5-x) }\\
=&\frac15\sin\frac\pi5\left(\cot(\frac{2\pi}5+x)+\cot(\frac{2\pi}5-x) \right)\\
&\hspace{1cm}+\frac15\sin\frac{2\pi}5\left(\cot(\frac{\pi}5+x)+\cot(\frac{\pi}5-x) \right)
\end{align}
Apply $(\ln \sin t)’= \cot t$ to integrate
$$\int \frac{\sin (3x)}{\sin(5x)}dx= \frac15\sin\frac{\pi}5\>\ln \frac{\sin(\frac{2\pi}5+x) }{\sin(\frac{2\pi}5-x) } +\frac15\sin\frac{2\pi}5\>\ln \frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}5+x) }{\sin(\frac\pi5-x) }+C
$$